# Mysql Query Exclude a certain entry

Tags: mysql, set

I'm trying to SELECT entries of a certain type, name, EXCLUDING  entries with the same name in a particular id.  The last part is the tricky part that I can't get my head around.

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE type = $type AND (name is not contained in an entry with id).
```

I want the result to be the set of all names that ARE of a certain type but NOT already included in a current id.

Do I need to execute two queries here? Or can I condense it to one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a subquery for this:

```
SELECT name
FROM table
WHERE type = $type
AND name NOT IN (SELECT entry FROM t WHERE id = $id );
```

Comment: Thanks Zed, one more thing -- what if I have more than one "name" to compare. Something like AND name, criteria, rank NOT IN (SELECT * FROM t ...) doesn't work, where i want to make sure name AND criteria AND rank are NOT in

Comment: I know I can just do more subqueries, but again, can i condense it to one?

Answer (score 2):

If you compare multiple values to a row returned by a subquery this way:

```
SELECT name FROM table
WHERE type = $type 
AND (name, criteria, rank) NOT IN 
  (SELECT name, criteria, rank FROM t WHERE id = $id );
```

You must make sure the list `(name, criteria, rank)` matches the columns selected in the subquery.  You shouldn't use `SELECT *`.

Comment: Thanks Bill, that fixed my issue -- had to accept Zed's answer, but thanks anyways.

Comment: No problem, Zed's answer was more specific to your first question.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like so:

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE type = $type 
                       AND name not in ('larry','moe','curly').
```

Could you provide a little more detail on your schema?  Concrete examples always help.

Comment: It's pretty much exactly what Zed gave, cept I have more than one "name" field to NOT match on